# My XSLT Variable doesn't load in template

Tags: xslt

So I'm trying to create a variable and then later on use this in my template.

This is the code I have now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="items">
  <xsl:call-template name="item" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="item">
  <xsl:for-each select="item">
    <xsl:variable name="currentItemTheme">
      test variable
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="title = name">
      Showvariable: {$currentItemTheme} <br/>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work. My file does output the "Showvariable: ", but it just doesn't show the test values. So the for-each loops and template aren't the problem.

[image]

Is there something I'm missing? Does someone know how I get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `<xsl:value-of select="$currentItemTheme"/>` instead of `{$currentItemTheme}`, unless you are mixing the XSLT code with some other language that provides the `{$currentItemTheme}` syntax.

`<xsl:copy-of select="$currentItemTheme"/>` is another option if you build nodes in your variable and want to output them instead of just the string value as a text node.

Comment: Was just thinking the same!

Comment: Ah right! I was using smarty before haha. This works, thanks! This raises another question for me.. My <xsl:if> function doesn't work now. I'll ask this in a new question.